# Getting last character of variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to get the  last character of a variable. 'var' is getting **q1d** from that select.

I want to get d in **qwer** var. Maybe its duplicated question but I am asking why those doesn't work ?

```
> slice, substr, split ?

      var qwer=$('.chkbox[value="' + $('#tablebody tr:last td:last-child').text() + '"]').attr("id");
      alert(qwer);// alerting q1d
      qwer.slice(-1); // i tried slice, substr, split but all same 
      alert(qwer);// alerting still q1d
```

Comment: add html mark up as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing to declare the variable of `slice result` .`slice` not affect the original variable its just returning .so you need re declare the result value of slice otherwise its call the first declared result only

```js
qwer = 'qId'
qwer = qwer.slice(-1);
console.log(qwer);
```

Comment: yes sir i got when i slice i need to put it back to variable otherwise sliced variable gone. Very explained thank you

Answer (score 4):

you can just use the bracket notation to get the last character.

```js
qwer = 'qId'
qwer = qwer[qwer.length-1];
console.log(qwer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because strings are immutable in JavaScript, none of the functions you mention modify the string in-place. You need to assign the result of the operation back to a variable:

```js
let qwer = 'q1d';
qwer = qwer.slice(-1);

console.log(qwer);
```

Comment: thank you i though when i slice its put  back to variable default. I got it thank you i ask so stupid question

Answer (score 1):

```
var qwer = "qId";
var lastChar = qwer.substr(qwer.length - 1); // => "d"
console.log(lastChar);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(qwer.slice(-1));
```

or

```
qwer = qwer.slice(-1);alert(qwer);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use `.split()` - make array of letters
2. use `.pop()` - get last element of array of letters

```js
var qwer = "q1d";

alert(qwer.split('').pop())
```

Answer (score -1):

Try passing -1 to `substr`; if a negative parameter is passed it is treated as `strLength - parameter` where `strLength` is the length of the string (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)):

```
qwer.substr(-1)
```